# How to wait until signal

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

I want make a while loop to wait and continue only when it receives signal

For example in while.py

```
        while queue:
             #wait until signal
             #bla bla
```

And when I hit button on my flask server it should send signal to this loop to continue: in main.py

```
         def alarm():
             #trigger loop to continue
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the simple producer-consumer example, ([see source](http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/10/producer-consumer-problem-in-python/))

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time
import random

queue = []
lock = Lock()

class ProducerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        nums = range(5) #Will create the list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
        global queue
        while True:
            num = random.choice(nums) #Selects a random number from list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
            lock.acquire()
            queue.append(num)
            print "Produced", num 
            lock.release()
            time.sleep(random.random())


class ConsumerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global queue
        while True:
            lock.acquire()
            if not queue:
                print "Nothing in queue, but consumer will try to consume"
            num = queue.pop(0)
            print "Consumed", num 
            lock.release()
            time.sleep(random.random())


ProducerThread().start()
ConsumerThread().start()
```

## Explanation:

We started one producer thread (hereafter referred as producer) and one consumer thread (hereafter referred as consumer). The producer keeps adding to the queue while consumer keeps on removing from the queue. Since `queue` is a shared variable, we keep it inside the lock to avoid a race condition.

At some point, the consumer has consumed everything and the producer is still sleeping. The consumer tries to consume more but since `queue` is empty, an `IndexError` is raised. But on every execution, before the `IndexError` is raised you will see the print statement for "Nothing in queue, but consumer will try to consume", which explains why you are getting the error.

Comment: This solution is inelegant and wrong, proper behavior of a producer is to simply wait until items are added, rather than to raise an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0):

@developer_hatch's `time.sleep(random.random())` solution is poor, as it raises an `IndexError` based on timing where it should simply wait for a bit.

It's better to use a `Condition` object, they allow to acquire a lock, but then release it for a bit until a condition is met.

I also suggest to use the `with` syntax whenever you can for readability and to avoid forgetting to release.

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread, Condition

queue = []
lock = Condition() # Condition, rather than Lock

class Producer(Thread):
  def run(self):
    global queue
    while True:
      time.sleep(np.random.rand())
      task = f'some task {np.random.randint(0, 100)}'
      with lock:
        queue.append(task)
        print(f"Produced: {task}")
        lock.notify() # Notifies other threads the condition might be changed, i.e. `wait`/`wait_for` will get a turn.

class Consumer(Thread):
  def run(self):
    global queue
    while True:
      with lock:
        lock.wait_for(lambda: len(queue) > 0) # Temporarily unlocks, such that other threads alter the condition
        print(f"Consumed: {queue.pop()}")
        time.sleep(np.random.rand())

Producer().start()
Consumer().start()
```

If you wish for the consumer to stop at some point, either let the `wait_for` also check for a 'finished' condition, e.g. as set by the producer, or add some type of Sentinel task that causes the consumer to break from the `while`-loop.